# how to add multiple conditions in ElasticSearch conditionally?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

on the following filter query:

```
 var searchResults = _client.Search<MyIndexable>(s => s
        .Query(q => q
            .Bool(b => b
                .Must(
                    subQuery => subQuery.QueryString(qs => qs.OnFields(f => f.Title, f => f.Description).Query(searchTerm + "*"")),
                    subQuery => subQuery.Term(f => f.field1, "some string"),
                    subQuery => subQuery.Term(f => f.field2 , "some Guid")))));
```

I wanted to add each filter below conditinally under Must. like

```
 if (request.field2)
     ubQuery.Term(f => f.field1, "some string"
```

can anyone help me to do this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in Nest. See the code below:

```
var funcs = new List<Func<QueryDescriptor<MyIndexable>, QueryContainer>>();
funcs.Add(subQuery.QueryString(qs => qs.OnFields(f => f.Title, f => f.Description).Query(searchTerm + "*"")));

if (request.field2) // I believe this is some bool variable
{
    funcs.Add(subQuery => subQuery.Term(f => f.field1, "some string"));
}

funcs.Add(subQuery => subQuery => subQuery.Term(f => f.field2 , "some Guid"));

var searchResults = _client.Search<MyIndexable>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(funcs.ToArray()))));
```

Comment: bittusarkar, how do I get subQuery instance to add filter Under BoolFilterDescriptor(Must) on the above case ?. like I need to add ExistFilter instead of QueryString and then terms filters conditionally ?

Comment: "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "Cid"
              }
            },
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "prf"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "IsActive": true
              }
            },

Comment: You don't need to define subQuery anywhere. It is part of the `Func` definition. The code that I've pasted is syntactically correct. You can replace `QueryString` with any other query you want to implement.

Comment: oh..yes I got it. in my case I used FilterDescriptor instead of QueryDescriptor per above json filter string.. and its working fine. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult for you because of method chaining.

It's more handable to set the configuration in json. Because json is a string, it's simple to break it and insert conditions, etc.

Example:

```
$config = '{
    "query":
    {';

if (condition) {
    $config .= '"match":
    {
        "foo": "bar"
    }';   
}

$config .= '
    }
}';
```

Of course, you're free to choose the way to build a json string.